# What is the correct way to express my thought about something I discovered was not easy?

Tags: sentence-structure

Let me give you a context.

I go to a Zumba class thinking it would be easy compared to Gym n all and find my body is tired and I am completely exhausted within one hour of Zumba. So not easy for me. I walk up to someone want to say it was surprisingly not easy.

What is the correct way to say this and what category of sentences this falls into?

```
declarative sentence (statement)
interrogative sentence (question)
imperative sentence (command)
exclamative sentence (exclamation)
```

**Who thought Zumba would be difficult** ( because now I know it is difficult).

OR

**Who thought Zumba would be easy** (because I thought it was easy and throwing a sarcasm now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to phrase in your two examples is actually a *rhetorical question*, which is phrased as an interrogative sentence but does not require an answer.

If you asked:

> Who thought Zumba would be difficult?

... you wouldn't expect people to respond. If they actually replied with "Me. I knew it was difficult" then they have misunderstood your intention which was to make a statement about how difficult *you* found it.

Sarcasm relies very much on tone of voice, so it can be a bit tricky for non-native English speakers. If you get the tone wrong what you say could be taken at face value.

So if you said:

> Who thought Zumba would be easy?

... some people might think you were boasting how easy it was for you. That said, if you were bent double and out of breath when you said it then it might be more obvious you are being sarcastic!

If all you want to do is express surprise at how difficult it was then maybe just make a straightforward declaration/exclamation and say:

> I never knew Zumba would be this difficult!